# Add custom css to shopping cart page

Tags: magento2

I would like to add custom css to shopping cart page. Where can I place the custom less file and where can I add the link to that file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create your own theme at below location **`app/design/frontend/Package/theme`**

In that add the module of checkout with directory name **`Magento_Checkout`**

Simply add your custom `css` for the checkout page at the below location.

**For `css` files**

> `magento_root\app\design\frontend\Package\theme\Magento_Checkout\web\css\Custom.css`

**for `.less` files**

> `magento_root\app\design\frontend\Package\theme\Magento_Checkout\web\css\source\module\_checkout.less`

**Note:**

> Disable the catch before doing adding the css or don't forget to run the below commands.
>
> **`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`**
>
> **`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`**

Comment: I observed that the styles ended up in styles-l.css. Now I need to figure out how to pull in common styles from my custom css that I did for other pages located in app/design/frontend/MyTheme/default/web/css/mytheme.less. Thanks @abhishek